# onFailure не могу прочитать и вывести ответ сервера

Tags: java, json, retrofit2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   public class Client {

```
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://client-api.instaforex.com/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

        logging.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

         retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
}


----------

    public class ModelGet {
        @SerializedName("Id")
        @Expose
        private Integer id;
        @SerializedName("ActualTime")
        @Expose
        private Integer actualTime;
        @SerializedName("Comment")
        @Expose
        private String comment;
        @SerializedName("Pair")
        @Expose
        private String pair;
        @SerializedName("Cmd")
        @Expose
        private Integer cmd;
        @SerializedName("TradingSystem")
        @Expose
        private Integer tradingSystem;
        @SerializedName("Period")
        @Expose
        private String period;
        @SerializedName("Price")
        @Expose
        private Double price;
        @SerializedName("Sl")
        @Expose
        private Double sl;
        @SerializedName("Tp")
        @Expose
        private Double tp;


        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Integer getActualTime() {
            return actualTime;
        }

        public void setActualTime(Integer actualTime) {
            this.actualTime = actualTime;
        }

        public String getComment() {
            return comment;
        }

        public void setComment(String comment) {
            this.comment = comment;
        }

        public String getPair() {
            return pair;
        }

        public void setPair(String pair) {
            this.pair = pair;
        }

        public Integer getCmd() {
            return cmd;
        }

        public void setCmd(Integer cmd) {
            this.cmd = cmd;
        }

        public Integer getTradingSystem() {
            return tradingSystem;
        }

        public void setTradingSystem(Integer tradingSystem) {
            this.tradingSystem = tradingSystem;
        }

        public String getPeriod() {
            return period;
        }

        public void setPeriod(String period) {
            this.period = period;
        }

        public Double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(Double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public Double getSl() {
            return sl;
        }

        public void setSl(Double sl) {
            this.sl = sl;
        }

        public Double getTp() {
            return tp;
        }

        public void setTp(Double tp) {
            this.tp = tp;
        }

    }


----------

    PostApi api = Client.getRetrofit().create(PostApi.class);
    private void getSecret() {
        Call<ModelGet> call = api.getSecret(token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelGet>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ModelGet> call, Response<ModelGet> response) {

                ModelGet ModelGet = response.body();

                String content = "";
                    content += "Id"+ModelGet.getId()+"n";
                    content += "ActualTime"+ModelGet.getActualTime()+"n";
                    content += "Comment"+ModelGet.getComment()+"n";
                    content += "Pair"+ModelGet.getPair()+"n";
                    content += "Cmd"+ModelGet.getCmd()+"n";
                    content += "TradingSystem"+ModelGet.getTradingSystem()+"n";
                    content += "Period"+ModelGet.getPeriod()+"n";
                    content += "Price"+ModelGet.getPrice()+"n";
                    content += "Si"+ModelGet.getSl()+"n";
                    content += "Tp"+ModelGet.getTp()+"n";

                answerTextView.setText(content);

                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    answerTextView.setText("Code: " +response.code());
                    return;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ModelGet> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(AnswerActivity.this, "error:(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}


----------

    public interface PostApi {

   @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
    @POST("api/Authentication/RequestMoblieCabinetApiToken")
    Call<User> createAccount(@Body Account account);

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @GET("clientmobile/GetAnalyticSignals/20234561?tradingsystem=3&pairs=GBPJPY,EURJPY&from=1479860023&to=1480066860")
    Call<ModelGet>  getSecret(@Header("passkey") String autchToken);
}
```

Comment: Так у Вас же ответ 200 - ОК, он не должен попадать в onFailure

Comment: Да но вместо вывода данных в активити он выдает error прописанное в onFailure. Просто будто не читаются полученные данные ответа.

Comment: Залоггируйте ошибку (`Throwable t`) и стек-трейс, так будет хоть что-то понятно

Comment: Вот весь лог. Я не вижу в нем ошибку. Или я не туда смотрю?

Comment: Я не вижу чтобы вы логгировали ошибку в коде `onFailure`, поэтому ее и не видно нигде в логе

Comment: получил вот это : Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path на лог Log.v("Project", String.valueOf(t));

Comment: Это означает, что Ваша модель ожидает JSON объект, а запрос возвращает JSON массив. Исправьте модель, и будет вам щастье :)

Comment: Спасибо попробую. Понять еще как это сделать.

Comment: Я не очень уже помню как это изящно сделать в GSON, но попробуйте просто поменять тип `Callback` на `Callback<List<ModelGet>>`

Comment: Получилось по этому способу , через RecyclerView вывести данные --- https://medium.com/@dds861/json-arrays-parsing-using-retrofit-and-recycleview-9b2d494cc24c